# js cookie is not shown in chrome developer tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, developer-tools

I created cookie with server side code (c#) and it was shown in chrome developer tools. (Resources->Cookies)
now I created it in js and it is not shown there anymore.
if I write in the console: "document.cookie" - I can see my cookie, but I want to see it in Resources->Cookies so I can easily delete it when I want to.
the code to create the cookie: (from: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp?output=print)

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
var exdate = new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" +   exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

and:

```
setCookie("myCookie", "true", 365);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refresh the resources inspector (small refresh icon in the bottom of the dev tools tray) before it appears.

Comment: Thanks, but it did not help. I even closed and opened the browser - and the cookie didn't appear.

Comment: Are you defining the `domain` when setting the cookie?

Comment: Hmm, should be fine then - a cookie without an explicit domain should use the domain of the page that it's set on. In my experience, the refresh trick always works!

Comment: Yeah, I copied your function into the console, called it with `setCookie('testicle','foo',365)` and it worked. Maybe a different dev tools version?

Comment: You're right, that is a problem only in this version of Chrome. (Version 12.0.742.122) I just checked on another computer and it works on Chrome version 19.0.1084.56. thank you!

Comment: @chrisfrancis27 yes i am defining the domain and i can't find it in dev tools but i can find it in my response. What should i do?

Answer (score 4):

Some updates on very similar topic. Secure cookies are not shown on insecure sites.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/rSbJ1m2F3HY

Comment: This was the correct answer for me.  I was debugging an application on localhost. The cookie was there but was filtered out by Chrome!

Inject the cooking a controller, you will see the JSESSIONID

`@CookieValue("JSESSIONID") cookie: String`

Answer (score 0):

As from experience, you'll need to refresh the cookies page after you implement the cookie with JS.

Answer (score 0):

Check the cookie settings in your browser and select Allow all cookies option and then refresh the page.