# Can't see jsessionid in chrome devtool?

Tags: google-chrome, session, google-chrome-devtools, session-cookies

After user's successful login I can't see JSESSIONID cookies in chrome devtool cookie panel (while it's visible in Firefox cookie panel),

in Chrome:

[image]

in Firefox:

[image]

but I can see it in chrome settings-all cookies page, why this? Any setting option in Chrome could solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are working on your local machine.

There was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295719/js-cookie-is-not-shown-in-chrome-developer-tools?rq) that led me to the right direction. **Chrome is hiding secure cookies for insecure sites** ([see here](https://groups.google.com/g/google-chrome-developer-tools/c/rSbJ1m2F3HY)).

I suggest you to inject the `JSESSIONID` to your controller to see the actual cookie value

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String hello(@CookieValue("foo") String fooCookie) {
    // ...
}
```